# How do I make DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader ignore non result classes?

Tags: perl, dbix-class

I'm switching from using [DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader](http://search.cpan.org/~rkitover/DBIx-Class-Schema-Loader-0.07033/lib/DBIx/Class/Schema/Loader.pm) in dynamic mode to static.

But there's a problem, my result classes are mixed up with non result classes.  [Here's the specifics](https://github.com/acme/parse-backpan-packages/tree/feature/schema_at_build/lib/BackPAN/Index).

```
lib/BackPAN/Index.pm            # main API
lib/BackPAN/Index/Dist.pm       # result class
lib/BackPAN/Index/File.pm       # result class
lib/BackPAN/Index/Release.pm    # result class
lib/BackPAN/Index/Schema.pm     # subclass of DBIC::Schema::Loader
lib/BackPAN/Index/Role/...      # various roles
```

When I switch to static schema generation it gets tripped up by the role.

> DBIx::Class::Schema::load_namespaces(): Attempt to load_namespaces()
>   class BackPAN::Index::Role::HasCache failed - are you sure this is a
>   real Result Class?

I'm stuck with this class layout. `BackPAN::Index::Dist`, `File` and `Release` are all publicly documented. Many methods are expected to return them as the result of queries.

I need a way to use [DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader](http://search.cpan.org/~rkitover/DBIx-Class-Schema-Loader-0.07033/lib/DBIx/Class/Schema/Loader.pm) in static mode while `BackPAN::Index::Dist`, `File` and `Release` are used as result classes.

I've been trying to make [DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader](http://search.cpan.org/~rkitover/DBIx-Class-Schema-Loader-0.07033/lib/DBIx/Class/Schema/Loader.pm) spell out the generated result classes rather than relying on `load_namespaces` to search the subdirectory.

Ideally, I'd like the generated result classes to be in their own subdirectory with `Dist`, `File` and `Release` as subclasses for easier customization. However, queries against the schema must return the customized subclasses.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you have a Result and a ResultSet namespace in which the corresponding classes reside:

```
BackPAN::Index::Schema::Result::Dist
BackPAN::Index::Schema::ResultSet::Dist
```

The [DBIx::Class::Schema#load_namespaces](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aSchema#load_namespaces) docs show an example of setting them to non-default values.

You can also use [DBIx::Class::Schema#load_classes](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aSchema#load_classes) and specify each class:

```
BackPAN::Index::Schema->load_classes({
    BackPAN::Index => [qw( Dist File Release )],
});
```

Normally it's not a problem to move Result and ResultSet classes into different namespaces because they are always accessed through an instance of the Schema which loads them.
I suggest trying to move them and see if it really breaks something before going with load_classes.

Comment: Yep, if I hard code the class list it works.  Trouble is, DBIC::Schema::Loader makes the Schema class.  How do I get control away from it?

Comment: Alternatively, if there's a way I can make DBIC::Schema::Loader only make the result classes and not the schema that would be handy.

Comment: Schema::Loader assumes an empty namespace in which it generates all types of classes. Modifying the generated schema (and also the other classes) is not only supported but assumed because its purpose is just to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I realized the important part of Schema::Loader is making the result classes.  The schema is simple and I can make it by hand.  Unfortunately there's no way to tell Schema::Loader not to generate the schema.  I've hacked around it by telling it to [make a dummy and just delete the file](https://github.com/acme/parse-backpan-packages/blob/feature/schema_at_build/inc/MyBuilder.pm).

```
DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader::make_schema_at(
    'BackPAN::Index::SchemaThrowaway',
    {
        result_namespace => '+BackPAN::Index',
        use_namespaces   => 1,
        dump_directory   => 'lib',
    },
);

# Throw the generated schema away.
unlink "lib/BackPAN/Index/SchemaThrowaway.pm";
```

Then I write the [schema class](https://github.com/acme/parse-backpan-packages/blob/feature/schema_at_build/lib/BackPAN/Index/Schema.pm) by hand.

```
package BackPAN::Index::Schema;

use strict;
use warnings;

use base 'DBIx::Class::Schema';

__PACKAGE__->load_classes({
    "BackPAN::Index" => [qw(Dist File Release)],
});
```

Its a hack, but it works.  Still looking for a better solution.